# expected unqualified-id before '[' token arduino

Tags: arduino

i created this code for an arduino adaptation of the board game quarto:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <SeeedTouchScreen.h>
#include <TFTv2.h>
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() {
Tft.TFTinit();
Serial.begin(115200);
bool[12][12] NUPieces;
}
void loop() {

}
```

but it returned this error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.5 (Windows 8), Board: "Arduino Uno"
Quarto.ino: In function 'void setup()':
Quarto:9: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
expected unqualified-id before '[' token
```

Comment: You'll have to declare the other dimension of the 2D array, both can't be unknown. Or you need to use `bool**`

Comment: i tried that, but it didnt work. thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the array incorrectly. The correct way would be:

```
bool NUPieces[12][12];
```